# ObjC Format Regex for Value of (Grails style) Key-Value Pair

Tags: objective-c, regex

So assuming a properties file like so (application.properties in Grails, for example):

```
app.name=An App Name
other.keys=Other Values
more.keys=More Values
```

I'm trying to write an Objective-C style regex to extract the value `An App Name`.

So far, using some sample code to test this out, heres what I've got:

```
    NSError *errRegex = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^app.name=(.*?)$"
                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                  error:&errRegex];


    NSUInteger countMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:strSource options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strSource length])];
    NSLog(@"Number of Matches: %ld", countMatches);

    NSLog(@"-----");

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:strSource options:0
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [strSource length])
                         usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match,
                                      NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                             NSLog(@"Ranges: %ld", [match numberOfRanges]);

                             NSString *matchFull = [strSource substringWithRange:[match range]];
                             NSLog(@"Match: %@", matchFull);

                             for (int i = 0; i < [match numberOfRanges]; i++) {
                                 NSLog(@"\tRange %i: %@", i,
                                       [strSource substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:i]]);
                             }                              
                         }];

    if (errRegex) {
        NSLog(@"%@", errRegex);
    }
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
2013-12-11 11:34:54.408 test[7321:303] Number of Matches: 1
2013-12-11 11:34:54.409 test[7321:303] -----
2013-12-11 11:34:54.409 test[7321:303] Ranges: 2
2013-12-11 11:34:54.410 test[7321:303] Match: app.name=An App Name        other.keys=Other     Values        more.keys=More Values
2013-12-11 11:34:54.410 test[7321:303]  Range 0: app.name=An App Name        other.keys=Other Values        more.keys=More Values
2013-12-11 11:34:54.410 test[7321:303]  Range 1: An App Name        other.keys=Other Values        more.keys=More Values
```

I'm assuming I need to end the regex at a newline character, but anything I've tried returns 0 matches.

Comment: Can you log out what strSource is: `NSLog(@"%@", strSource);` and tell us what that is?

Comment: @moby It's exactly what it is at the top.

Comment: So there are \n at the end of each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^app\.name=(.*)
```

Comment: Returns the exact same results.

Comment: @KyleBanks perhaps you need to escape the period. Try `^app\.name=(.*)`